# If I have the choice, should webpage contents be saved on the file system or in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, html, apache, filesystems

I am in the planning stages of writing a CMS for my company. I find myself having to make the choice between saving page contents in a database or in folders on a file system. I have learned that PHP performs admirably well reading and writing to file systems, way better in fact than running SQL queries. But when it comes to saving pages and their data on a file system, there'll be a lot more involved than just reading and writing. Since pages will be drawn using a PHP class, the data for each page will be just data, no HTML. Therefore a parser for the files would have to be written. Also I doubt that all the data from a page will be saved in just one file, it would rather be saved in one directory, with content boxes and data in separated files.

All this would be done so much easier with MySQL, so what I want to ask you experts:

Will all the extra dilly dally with file system saving outweigh it's speed and resource advantage over MySQL?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here.

You should save the information to display on each page in the database, such as, company names, client names, etc. It makes sense and provides an easy way to access information in a structured way.

However, when you get the full result of a page, I don't think it will be a good idea to store that into the database, instead, store that into a file and use it as cache (maybe add a cache expiration feature too).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have learned wrong. it's imaginable "outweigh".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for MySQL. I'd say the only time you should think about using the file system is when you are storing files (BLOBS) of several megabytes, databases (at least the ones you typically use with a php website) are generally less performant when storing that kind of data. For the rest I'd say: always use a relational database. (Assuming you are dealing with data dat *has* relations of course, if it is random data there is not much benefit in using a relational database ;-)

Addition: If you define your own file-structure, and even your own way of cross referencing files you've already started building a 'database' yourself, that is not bad in itself -- it might be loads of fun! -- but you probably will not get the performance benefits you're looking for unless your situation is radically different than the other 80% of 'standard' websites on the web (a couple of pages with text and images on them). (If you are building google/youtube/flickr/facebook ... you've got a different situation and developing your own unique storage solution starts making sense)

Comment: I'm forced to disagree with you. Big files or small files doesn't matter so much to me, in the end, it really depends on your usecase. For exemple, one could use GridFS of mongodb as a pseudo filesystem to keep files revisions and make replication of all files to multiple slave server. I also think that deciding files in database for speed is a premature optimisation. One should only do what fits his needs and once things work. Try to find what is slow. I personally don't know how slow mysql can be with blobs but I believe it shouldn,t be so slow.

Comment: @Symbiam: That is why I say 'think about' not 'blindly do without any additional information or tests' ;-) You certainly make some valid points, but I don't think they really matter in relation to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

things to consider

- race-condition in file write if two user editing same piece of content
- distribute file across multiple servers if CMS growth, latency on replication will cause data integrity problem
- search performance, grep on files on multiple directory will be very slow
- too many files in same directory will cause server performance especially in windows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a low-traffic, single-server environment here…

If you expect to ever have to manage those entries outside of the CMS, my opinion is that it's much, *much* easier to do so with existing tools than with database access tools.

For example, there's huge value in being able to use awk, grep, sed, sort, uniq, etc. on textual data. Proxying that through a database makes this hard but not impossible.

Of course, this is just opinion based on experience.

S

Answer (score 0):

Storing Data on the filesystem may be faster for large blobs that are always accessed as one piece of information. When implementing a CMS, you typically don't only have to deal with such blobs but also with structured information that has internal references (like content fields belonging to a certain page that has links to other pages...). SQL-Databases provide an easy way to access structured information, files on your filesystem do not (except of course simple hierarchical structures that can be represented with folders).

So if you wanted to store the structured data of your cms in files, you'd have to use a file format that allows you to save the internal references of your data, e.g. XML. But that means that you would have to parse those files, which is not only a lot of work but also makes the process of accessing the data slow again.

In short, use MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Use a database and you have lots of important [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) from the beginning "for free" without inventing them in some suboptimal ways if you go the filesystem way. If you don't want to be constrained to MySQL only you can make use of e.g. the database abstraction layer [of the doctrine project](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Additionally you have tools like phpMyAdmin for easy lookup or manipulation of your data versus the texteditor.

Keep in mind that the result of your database queries can almost always be cached in memory or even in the filesystem so you have the benefit of easier management with well known tools and similar performance.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to minor modifications of website contents (eg. fixing a typo or updating external links), I find it much easier to connect to the server using SSH and use various tools (text editors, grep etc.) on files, rather than I having to use CMS interface to update each file manually (our CMS has such interface).

Yet there are several questions to analyze and answer, mentioned above - do you plan for scalability, concurrent modification of data etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not be worth it.

And there is no advantage to using the filesystem over a database unless you are the only user on the system (in which the advantage would be lost anyway). As soon as the transactions start rolling in and updates cascades to multiple pages and multiple files you will regret that you didn't used the database from the beginning :)

If you are set on using caching, experiment with some of the existing frameworks first. You will learn a lot from it. Maybe you can steal an idea or two for your CMS?